# Erro com o Like do sql

Tags: sql, sql-select, operador-like

Como faço para extrair da BD todos os campos que começam com '1.'? Na minha instrução usei o LIKE mas não teve qualquer retorno, mas se retirar o ponto já retorna algo, mas retorna campos que eu não quero, exemplo: 10.1;
O que tem de errado.

```
SELECT * FROM tbCelula WHERE C_Numeracao LIKE '1.%';
```

> ```
> tbCelula
> C_id     C_Numeracao
> 1        1.1
> 2        10.1
> 3        1.1.1
> 4        2.1
> ```

Retorno
1.1; 1.1.1

Comment: qual banco vc esta usando?

Comment: Estou a usar o access.

Comment: Aparentemente seu código esta coreto, no sql server ele faz certo,   o seu  C_Numeracao é de que tipo ?

Comment: É do tipo texto.

Comment: Certifica-te de que estás a escapar esse valor como deve ser.

Comment: Solução: SELECT * FROM tbCelula WHERE Mid(C_Numeracao, 1, 2) = '1.'; Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: vou remover  a minha resposta, para limpar a área.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `SubString`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbCelula WHERE SUBSTRING(C_Numeracao FROM 1 FOR 1) = 1
```

Dependendo do caso você precisara fazer um CAST na SubString passando ela para Inteiro, de toda forma é fácil fazer!

```
SELECT * FROM tbCelula WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(C_Numeracao FROM 1 FOR 1) AS INTEGER) = 1
```

Comment: No meu caso só tive de trocar o substring pelo Mid, mas o post ajudou. Obrigado.